# Create a tree recursivly

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I want to create a Treeview in C# which will group file by prefix (here the prefix is a marked by the separator `_`). The following files should give this tree:

### Files list:

> ```
> p_a
> p_a_test
> p_LIG
> p_p
> p_p_c
> p_p_c2
> p_p_ccc
> p_p_test
> p_tres
> TestLineGraph1
> TestLineGrpah
> ```

### Corresponding tree:

> ```
> |--p_
>     |--p_a
>     |--p_a_test
>     |--p_LIG
>     |--p_p
>     |--p_p_
>         |--p_p_c
>         |--p_p_c2
>         |--p_p_ccc
>         |--p_p_test
>     |--p_tres
> TestLineGraph1
> TestLineGraph
> ```

And how I do it:

```cs
 private GraphUINode(List<string> subNodes, GraphUINode parent, string name, int lvl = 0)
        : base(parent.m_viewDataSubControl)
{
    parent.Nodes.Add(this);
    this.Name = name;
    this.Text = name;

    string currentPrefix = "";
    int pertinentSubNodes = 0;
    while (pertinentSubNodes < subNodes.Count -1 && subNodes[pertinentSubNodes].Split('_').Length < 2+ lvl)
        pertinentSubNodes++;

    for (int i = 0; i <= lvl; i++)
    {
        currentPrefix += subNodes[pertinentSubNodes].Split('_')[i] + "_";
    }
    List<String> children = new List<string>();
    foreach (string child in subNodes)
    {
        // The child is in the same group than the previous one
        if (child.StartsWith(currentPrefix))
        {
            children.Add(child);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a node only if needed
            if (children.Count > 1)
            { 
                 // Create the new node
                new GraphUINode(children, this, currentPrefix, lvl + 1);
                children.Clear();
                children.Add(child);
            }
            else
            {
                if (children.Count == 1)
                {
                    new GraphTemplateNode(this, m_viewDataSubControl, children[0]);
                    children.Clear();
                }
                new GraphTemplateNode(this, m_viewDataSubControl, child);
            }
            currentPrefix = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= lvl; i++)
            {
                currentPrefix += child.Split('_')[i] + "_";
            }                    
        }
    }
    if (children.Count == 1)
    {
        new GraphTemplateNode(this, m_viewDataSubControl, children[0]);
        children.Clear();
    }
}
```

but this looks very dirty. How can I improve it?

Comment: I like ANSII art. ++

Comment: @RubberDuck thanks dude, now I can call myself an artist!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is this a bug ?**

The correspondending tree you showed is **not consistent**.  It should look like

```
|--p_
    |--p_a
    |--p_a_
          |--p_a_test  <- this
    |--p_LIG
    |--p_p
    |--p_p_
        |--p_p_c
        |--p_p_c2
        |--p_p_ccc
        |--p_p_test
    |--p_tres
TestLineGraph1
TestLineGraph
```

**Style**

- You should always be consistent with the coding style you use. So if you omit (<-bad) braces `{}` for loops with a single statement, you should stick to it.
- You shouldn't shorten variable / parameter names because that removes readability. -> `lvl`

**Comments**

Comments should describe **why** something is done. **What** is done should be described by the code itself by using meaningful names for classes, methods, parameters.

A comment which describes **what** is done like

> ```
>  // Create the new node
> new GraphUINode(children, this, currentPrefix, lvl + 1);
> ```

should be removed.

**Refactoring**

Can't be done until the possibility of the bug as mentioned is cleared.

As the root problem to solve is to create a tree structure based on a `List<string>` I would extract this tree creation outside of the constructor to a separate method which only takes a `List<string>` as input parameter and is returning something like

```
class TreeNode
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public IList<TreeNode> ChildNodes { get; private set; }
    public TreeNode()
    {
        ChildNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    }
    public void FillChildNodes(IList<String> childNodes)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: in fact, as the category p_a_ contains only 1 child I don't consider it as a node (should I?). Thanks for the comment advice, I'll fix it in my code immediately!

Comment: I would consider it as a node.